# Supress single warning/error message

Tags: r, warnings, suppress-warnings

I would like to prevent a function from warning me.

```
>for (v in c("1", "a2", "aaa", 10)) 
  if (is.na(as.numeric(v))) 
    cat("\nWarning:", paste(v, "cannot be coerced into a number"))

Warning: a2 cannot be coerced into a number
Warning: aaa cannot be coerced into a number
Warning messages:
1: NAs introduced by coercion
2: NAs introduced by coercion
```

I would like only my warnings to be displayed: `Warning: a2 cannot be coerced into a number` and `Warning: aaa cannot be coerced into a number`.

I assume there are two ways to do this.
1. Override the warning that R uses.
2. Suppress the warning that R uses.

Help with either would be informative but I am more interested in suppressing the warning system.

Thanks for any help you can provide!
Francis

Comment: It won't work, because the warning is made using `cat`. If you change `cat` to `message` or `warning`, you're good to go as @hrbrmstr suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
for (v in c("1", "a2", "aaa", 10)) 
    if (is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(v))))
        warning(paste(v, "cannot be coerced into a number"))
```

`suppressWarnings` evaluates expression and ignores warnings.

`warning` generates your own warning :)